# web deploy url paths mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

When I deploy my mvc app I am having difficulty getting my paths to work correctly when moving between pages (views).

Basically in my development environment my landing page is localhost:1910/ whereas when I deploy it, my landing page is localhost/ITSMngr.

Therefore all my links keep missing the ITSMngr section.  eg If I have a link such as:

```
<a href="/DataBaseMng/Edit?id=@signData.SignDataId" >
```

where DataBaseMng is the name of a controller and Edit the action, it works fine in my dev environment because it will ultimately map it to localhost/DataBaseMng/Edit?id=2 or something.  Whereas when deployed it will try to map to the same path but won't work because it misses the ITSMngr section. ie it should map to localhost/ITSMngr/DataBaseMng/Edit?id=2

Is there a way to set that up by default somewhere so it always will put in ITSMngr for me?  I've tried changing the map routes in Global.asax.cs but it doesnt' work - not that I'm 100% convinced I'm doing it correctly.

Removing the / at the beginning of my links will work once, but when you navigate back again, it's internal paths are all shot and it might lo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an MVC application you should use the built-in functions to generate URLS instead of hard coding them. This should take care of it all for you, and make use of the Routes defined in your global.ascx

Instead of:

```
<a href="/DataBaseMng/Edit?id=@signData.SignDataId" >
```

Use:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "DataBaseMng", new { id = signData.SignDataId })" >
```

If you want to reference something using the Url rather than the Action helper method (not really recommended) then use:

```
@Url.Content("~/DataBaseMng/Edit?id=" + signData.SignDataId.ToString())
```

Note the ~ which asp .net will map to wherever you've installed the application

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't mention that I tried using the ~ which you suggested.  I like the @Url.Action better too, though, so I might try to implement that.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: If you use the ~ (useful for css, scripts, etc), it must be in a Url.Content function <a href="@Url.Content("~/DataBaseMng/Edit?id=" + signData.SignDataId.ToString())" >